# PHP Переход по ссылке с параметром

Tags: php

Всем салют!
Подскажите, как реализовать проверку на нужный url с параметром?

```php
    <?php 
        $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        var_dump($uri);
        if($uri === '/')
            require 'template/main.php';
        elseif($uri === '/customers'){
                if($uri === '/customers?active')
                    require 'template/active.php';
                elseif($uri === '/customers?history')
                    require 'template/history.php';
                else
                    require 'template/customers.php';
        }
        else
            require 'template/404.php';
         

    ?>
```

необходимо, что бы при переходе по ссылке /customers?active=1 открывалась нужная страница, а меня редиректит на 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо вы пытаетесь сделать свой `MVC` и не понимаете с чего начать. [Вот хороший материал для начинающего](https://habr.com/ru/post/150267/). Сразу же обратите внимание на маршрутизатор URL.

Вернемся к вопросу. Вы сравниваете строку c точным значением, а ваша строка длиннее этого значения. В результате и получаете 404 по `else`.

Что сделать в вашем случае? Применить [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php), и сравнивать нужное количество символов `$uri` c нужной строкой, соответственно строка с условием должна выглядеть вот так (прошу обратить внимание, что это только конкретный пример для частного случая):

```
elseif(substr($uri, 0, 10) === '/customers')
```

Comment: спасибо, материал изучу.
Получается вы предлагаете сравнивать явное количество символов, да?

Comment: @Amicrone, вы сравниваете строку `/customers?active=1` с `/customers` - поэтому результат сравнения `false`. А раз вы хотите убедиться, что запрос именно к `/customers`, то нужно из первоначальной строки выдернуть 10 символов с помощью `substr`. Так понятней? Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял:)